# What is the smallest $d$ such that $4$ has more than one distinct factorization in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})}$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Or if there is no such $d$, how do I prove it?

Obviously there is no point to looking for this in an UFD. I've looked in other rings, and each time I think I found it, I divide one of the factors by $2$ and find a unit, e.g.,:

$$\frac{38 + 12 \sqrt{10}}{2} = 19 + 6 \sqrt{10}$$

$$\frac{8 + 2 \sqrt{15}}{2} = 4 + \sqrt{15}$$

$$\frac{102 + 20 \sqrt{26}}{2} = 51 + 10 \sqrt{26}$$

$$\frac{22 + 4 \sqrt{30}}{2} = 11 + 2 \sqrt{30}$$

$$\frac{70 + 12 \sqrt{34}}{2} = 35 + 6 \sqrt{34}$$

etc.

In general, it seems that if the "integer" part and the "surd" part have the same parity, it will turn out to just be a unit doubled.

Comment: I think that in the last line you meant to say that if the "integer part" and the "surd part" are both even, then the number turns out to be a unit multiplied by 2 (I wouldn't say "doubled," though I'm not sure what about that word makes me uncomfortable here). I think maybe $d$ *has* to be odd, but of course that wouldn't rule out obtaining a factor that is a unit multiplied by 2, especially if $d \equiv 1 \mod 4$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\left( \frac{\sqrt{65}+7}{2} \right) \left( \frac{\sqrt{65}-7}{2} \right) =4.$$
Since $65 \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, this is an algebraic integer, and clearly $2$ does not divide $\left( \frac{\sqrt{65}+7}{2} \right)$. We need to check that $2$ and $\left( \frac{\sqrt{65}+7}{2} \right)$ are irreducible in $\mathbb{Z} \left[  \frac{1+\sqrt{65}}{2} \right]$. Since they both have norm $4$, we need to check that there is no element in the ring with norm $\pm 2$. We need to show we can't have $N \left(\frac{a+b\sqrt{65}}{2} \right) = \pm 2$ or equivalently, we can't have $a^2-65 b^2 = \pm 8$. This relation is impossible modulo $5$.

---

How I found this: Let's think about how the ideal $(2)$ can factor into prime ideals.

- $(2)$ stays prime. Then $4 = 2 \times 2$ is the only factorization.
- $(2) = \mathfrak{p} \mathfrak{q}$ is a product of principal ideals, $\mathfrak{p} = (a)$ and $\mathfrak{q}=(b)$. Then $4 = \pm a^2 b^2$ is the unique prime factorization (and we can show the sign is $+$, but that isn't important.)
- $(2) = \mathfrak{p}^2$ with $\mathfrak{p}$ non principal. Again,  $4 = 2 \times 2$ is the only factorization.

So the only option is that $2$ splits into distinct, non principal, primes. $2$ splits in the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ (for $d$ square free) if and only if $d \equiv 1 \bmod 8$.

So we are looking for $d \equiv 1 \bmod 8$, square free, and class number $>1$. The first such $d$ is $65$ (I looked in [this table](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ClassNumber.html)) and it works.

---

After thinking a bit more, there are infinitely many such examples. Find $k$ such that $8k+5$ and $8k+13$ are both squarefree. There are infinitely many such pairs, see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59741). Take $D = (8k+5)(8k+13)$. It is also squarefree, since no $p^2$ divides either factor and, if $p$ divided both $8k+5$ and $8k+13$, then it would divide $(8k+13)-(8k+5)=8$, but $8k+5$ and $8k+13$ are odd.

Now, $\left( \frac{8k+9 + \sqrt{D}}{2} \right) \left( \frac{8k+9 - \sqrt{D}}{2} \right) = 4$. As before, it is obvious that $2$ doesn't divide $(8k+9 \pm \sqrt{D})/2$. Finally, we must check that there is no solution to $x^2 - D y^2 = \pm 8$. We break into cases, based on the prime factorization of $8k+5$:

**Case 1** $8k+5$ is divisible by a prime $p$ which is $5 \bmod 8$. Then $\left( \frac{2}{p} \right) = \left( \frac{-2}{p} \right) = -1$, so $x^2 - D y^2 \equiv x^2 \bmod p$ cannot be $\pm 8$.

**Case 2** $8k+5$ is divisible by a prime $p$ which is $3 \bmod 8$, and another prime $q$ which is $7 \bmod 8$. Then $\left( \frac{2}{p} \right) = -1$ and $\left( \frac{-2}{q} \right) = -1$, so $x^2 - D y^2 = 8$ is impossible modulo $p$ and $x^2 - D y^2 = -8$ is impossible modulo $q$.

**Case 3** All prime divisors of $8k+5$ are either $1$ or $3$ mod $8$. But then $8k+5$ is $1$ or $3$ modulo $8$, a contradiction.

**Case 4** All prime divisors of $8k+5$ are either $1$ or $7$ mod $8$. But then $8k+5$ is $1$ or $7$ modulo $8$, a contradiction.

After staring for a little bit, you will see that one of these cases must hold; QED.

Comment: Very well done. I would only add that $d$ has to be positive, since 2 is prime/irreducible in almost all imaginary quadratic rings, a fact both you and the OP are probably aware of but the larger Audience might not.

Comment: @AlonsodelArte Actually, $(1+\sqrt{-15})/2 \times (1-\sqrt{-15})/2 = 2 \times 2$ also works. (Note that $x^2+15 y^2 = 8$ is impossible modulo $5$.) I had taken the OP to be asking about positive $d$. You're right, though, that there are no examples after this: For square free $d>15$, there are no elements of norm $4$ other than $\pm 2$ in the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$.

Comment: and since their's only $1$ and $-1$ for units in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-15})}$ those two factorizatons are infact distinct. bravo, David, Bravo!

Comment: But, David, isn't $7^2 - 65 = -16$ rather than $+16$? This detail would be an idiotic reason to downvote, but I think it does need to at least be mentioned in a comment. And Alfonso, didn't you already know about $-15$?

Comment: Good point, Bob, but I went ahead and accepted Dave's answer despite that little mistake.

Comment: @RobertSoupe I wrote $(\sqrt{65}+7)/2 \times (\sqrt{65}-7)/2 = 4$ quite carefully to get the sign right. Did I mess it up somewhere else that I'm not seeing?

Comment: @RobertSoupe Although, if you do want the other sign, just use $9^2 - 65 = 16$ instead.

Comment: @DavidSpeyer You're absolutely right, you got the sign right. My God, would I feel stupid if I had downvoted your answer over that! I suppose if I had come up with that solution I would have expressed it as $(-7 + \sqrt{65})/2 \times (7 + \sqrt{65})/2$.

Comment: And Alonzo used $(-1)\left(\frac{7}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{65}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{7}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{65}}{2}\right)$.